# getting an id from css using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I having a bit of a problem in my code. What I am trying t achieve is that I want to change some contents of CSS like changing the style of a page using javascript inside php, but I have an error saying there is no id or null

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["get_name"])) {
   
  $theName = $_POST["my_name"];
  echo "<script>
 document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById('name').style.display = 'none';

</script>";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<style>

#check { 
      background-color: yellow;
      color: black;
      border-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 15px;
      display: inline-block
}

#text { 
 display: none;
}

#name { 

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="name" action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="Your name here" required>
<input type="submit" name="get_name" value="Enter">
</form>

<form id="text" action="" method="post">
Your text: <textarea name="getText" row="10" col="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="get_text" value="Enter">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the field with `id="text"` ?

Comment: lemme update the code

Comment: I think you are using `script` tag in `style` tag!!

Comment: Code full updated can you help now??

Comment: I'll say it again, only louder: **you have no id's**.

Comment: @Fred-ii- <form id="text" action="" method="post">

Comment: @FelippeDuarte fair enough; now what about for the other 2?

Comment: And you dont have `id='name'` as @Fred-ii- says!

Comment: There are so many problems here that I'm afraid to start fixing :D

Comment: still same error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at localhost/:8

Answer (score 1):

You should put `script` tag in `head` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>


<?php

if (isset($_POST["get_name"])) { 

  $theName = $_POST["my_name"];  ?>

 <script>
 document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById('name').style.display = 'none';

</script>

<?php
 }
 ?>


<style>

#check { 
      background-color: yellow;
      color: black;
      border-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 15px;
      display: inline-block
}

#text { 
 display: none;
}

#name { 

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="Your name here" required>
<input type="submit" name="get_name" value="Enter">
</form>

<form id="text" action="" method="post">
Your text: <textarea name="getText" row="10" col="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="get_text" value="Enter">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @cleomaster I changed the `php`  section, Try it

Comment: I fixed it, I just had to put the php code in the body section, Anyway thanks alot.

Comment: @cleomaster you are welcome!  the standard way is to put script in head, but your code problem is that the document is not ready yet! put your script code in `(function() {......})();` !!